# Win32com events not raising inside thread?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I am new to both COM and Python, so im not very familiar with exact terminologies. So apologies for using inexact terms.

I am trying to connect to a desktop application via a proprietary COM interface using pywin32.
I created a PoC and it runs fine. The COM function call is processed and I get the expected event.

```
class MyEvents:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Callback class initialized")
        
    def OnMyEvent(self, data):
        print('MyEvent raised')

class ComUser:
    comObj = None    
        
    def __init__(self):
        comObj = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("ProproetaryInterface.InterfaceClass",
                                          MyEvents)
        comObj.Register()
        comObj.DoSomething(data)
        time.sleep(120)
        

userObj = ComUser()
```

So far so good. I get the event on the screen

> Callback class initialized
>
> MyEvent raised

Next I tried to put it into my application where I have multiple threads. To explain it in simple terms:
Main creates an object of Class X which initializes an XMLRPC Server thread.
The XMLRPC handler simply takes incoming info and puts it into a queue
The queue is from multiprocessing lib.
Another thread waits on this queue for an incoming message

```
def __startPollingThread(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        pollingThread = Thread(target=self.__checkQueue )
        pollingThread.start()
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

This is the polling thread method:

```
def __checkQueue(self):
        
        try:
            
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            while True:
                currMessage = self.__messageQueue.get() 
                self.__processMessage(currMessage);
        except :
            #Log message
        finally:
            pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

The __processMessage passes through multliple classes (something like a strategy pattern + state pattern) before it hits the class that handles COM interface.

In the ComUser class, i have a method which registers with the client application's com interface:

```
def initSystem(self):
        import pythoncom
        try:
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            self.ComConnector = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("ProprietaryInterface.InterfaceClass",
                                              MyEvents)
            self.ComConnector.Register()
            
        except:
        finally:
            pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Another method handles the specific requests as they arrive and makes the corresponding COM calls.

```
def handleMessage(self, message):
    #if message = this then
    comObj.DoSomething(data)
```

Both methods are called from the __processMessage method. All my classes reside in separate Py files. Except ComUser and MyEvents which are in same py module

I can call the Com Interface and see the Application reacting to the COM method calls but I cant see any events being raised. I have tried a whole lot of combinations of CoInitialize and Uninitialze and "import pythoncom" statements to ensure that it is not a problem with the threading. Also tried setting the sys.coinit_flags = 0  and checked. Seems to make no difference. I just dont see any events.

Is it a problem that I call DispatchWithEvents in a child thread instead of the main thread(The calls seem to work fine) ? Or is it that the main thread (ie **main** method of the program) dies out. I tried putting a long sleep there too.  I even tried a separate thread with PumpWaitingMessages loop but it made no difference. I cant think of any solutions.

Comment: If it helps: I amusing Python 3.4 with PyDev

Comment: OK! Ive finally solved the problem. If anybody wants I'll post the details. How do I mark this question as closed so that someone else doesn't waste time trying?

Comment: Answer your own question and accept the answer.